# multiprocessing running 1 thread at a time x amount of times

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing for a project which involves going to a URL. I have noticed that whenever I use `pool.imap_unordered()` whatever my iterator is (lets say it is a list with the number 1 and 2, that are 2 numbers), it will run the program once with one thread, then because there are 2 numbers in the list, it will run another time. I can't seem to figure this out. I thought I understood what everything should be doing. (no, it doesn't run any faster no matter how many threads I have) (the args.urls is originally a file then I convert all the content in the file to a list) everything worked fine until I added multiprocessing so I know it couldn't be an error in my non-multiprocessing related code.

```
from   multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import requests

arrange = [ lines.replace("\n", "") for lines in #file ]

def check():
    for lines in arrange:
        requests.get(lines)

def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    results = pool.imap_unordered(check, arrange)
```

Comment: [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) is a wrapper for the threading module and as such is limited by the same issues including the GIL. If you want to use multiprocessing do not use the dummy module

Comment: @IainShelvington i also used what i have in my code now

Comment: Why are you not passing arrange to the function but using the outer scope variable?  Your function check should accept arrange as an argument (I would name it differently though). Also in the example you give you import Pool but use ThreadPool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but maybe this is what you need:

```
from   multiprocessing import ThreadPool 
import multiprocessing
import requests

arrange = [ line.replace("\n", "") for line in #file ]


def check(line):
    requests.get(line) # remove the loop, since you are using multiprocessing this is not needed as you pass only one of the lines per thread. 


def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    results = pool.imap_unordered(check, arrange) #  This loops through arrange and provides the check function a single line per call
```